# How to define one method as both instance method and class method (sharing the same name), each with different arguments?

Tags: python, oop, overloading, class-method, instance-methods

In essence, I'm trying to accomplish the below but where `bar` and `baz` have the same handle (e.g. just `bar`) rather than being two differently-named functions.

###### Definitions

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.add # For example; real function will be different in every instance

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def bar(self):
        return foo(self.arg1, self.arg2)

    @classmethod
    def baz(cls, arg1, arg2):
        return foo(arg1, arg2)
```

###### Example Usage

```
a, b = 1, 2
mine = MyClass(a, b)
print(mine.bar())
>>> 3
```

```
x, y = 3, 4
print(MyClass.baz(x, y))
>>> 7
```

I'm trying to do this for intelligibility's sake. The real function names are long with many underscores, and making two slightly differently-named functions (e.g. prepending one function name with a `_`) for every function to which I want to do this is only going to confuse an already complicated situation.

The function will mostly be used internally, but I'd like the ability to call the function in a static context with ad hoc parameters that might not necessarily match the instance variables of a given object of `MyClass` (in fact, I would only call it this way if they didn't match). I'm using `@classmethod` rather than `@staticmethod` because the real functions use some internal class variables.

I've already tried simply implementing the above with `bar` for both function names, but as expected, the instance method has been overridden by the class method.

- I suppose one awkward solution would be to define `bar` as:

  ```
  def bar(self, arg1=None, arg2=None):
      if arg1 is None:
          arg1 = self.arg1
      if arg2 is None:
          arg2 = self.arg2
      return foo(arg1, arg2)
  ```

  and then, if I wanted to call it statically elsewhere, I would need to use:

  ```
  # Assuming that a specific object of MyClass does not exist yet
  useless = "not", "used"
  mine = MyClass(*useless)

  x, y = 6, 9
  print(mine.bar(x, y))
  ```

  I don't really like this because it requires me to call `bar` from a specific object of `MyClass`. This is technically not an issue if I already have an instance of `MyClass` somewhere, but I want a class method for a reason: `bar` in this context doesn't depend on any instance variables (though it does on class variables).
- Another potential solution would be to make a separate class for this function (and others):

  ```
  class Functions(object):
      @classmethod
      def bar(cls, arg1, arg2):
          return foo(arg1, arg2)
  ```

  and to call it within `MyClass` as `Functions.bar(self.arg1, self.arg2)` and externally as `Functions.bar(arg1, arg2)`

  I'm not super keen on this either since I'm putting `bar` and similar functions in `MyClass` for a reason: they're relevant to `MyClass` conceptually.

I saw some answers to similar SO posts that use Descriptors, but I was hoping there might be a more elegant solution.

Any wise Python wizards out here have advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let `self` take a default argument as well, so that you can distinguish between `mine.bar()` and `MyClass.bar()`. The price is that the other two arguments *must* be keyword arguments.

```
class MyClass:

    _sentinel = object()

    def bar(self=None, *, arg1=_sentinel, arg2=_sentinel):
        if self is not None:
            if arg1 is _sentinel:
                arg1 = self.arg1
            if arg2 is _sentinel:
                arg2 = self.arg2
        else:
            if arg1 is _sentinel:
                raise ValueError("Missing required arg1")
            if arg2 is _sentinel:
                raise ValueError("Missing required arg2")

        return foo(arg1, arg2)


mine.bar()  # self is mine, arg1 is _sentinel, arg2 is _sentinel

MyClass.bar(arg1=3, arg2=4)
```

Comment: Wow, I never would have thought of that! So if I understand correctly, normal calls from an instance of `My Class` always pass a reference to that instance as `self`, so the default value is always overridden. However, calling `bar` in a static context does not pass such a reference, so `None` is passed as default. That sound about right?

Comment: Just one question: why force kwargs? Does that just prevent the first argument from being passed as `self` in a static call?